# How to capture Publish Transaction TCM URI in Custom resolver

Tags: 2013, custom-resolver

Can we capture the PublishTransaction TCM URI in custom Resolver while publishing?

Comment: Yes you can. TOM.NET API provides this capability.

Comment: would you please elaborate more info...

Comment: Have a look at the Tom.net API docs.  Otherwise share what you've read/tried to solve this and specifically where you got stuck.

Comment: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishTransaction PT = new PublishTransaction(item.Id, context.Session);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. The resolver doesn't know/care about the concept of Publish Transactions. To elaborate on this, the method signature `Resolve` has 4 parameters, none of which you can use to somehow trace back the ID you are searching for. Also, take the following scenario for example, when in the Publish dialog you click `Show items to publish` the resolver gets triggered, but there is no Publish Transaction yet because a Publish action is not yet saved. The Id is assigned upon saving.